# Login not working on my website on google chrome only

Tags: php, google-chrome, cookies, authentication

My website is nearly ready to be released - an online game.  One of the final problems I am facing is that the login form does not seem to be working on Google Chrome on MOBILE only.  The website and form work perfectly on the Edge browser on mobile, and it also works perfectly on Chrome and all other browsers on PC - it's just Google Chrome on mobile for some reason.  It's important as users of the game will need mobile access as I believe that it's the way forward.

I imagine it's something to do with cookies/cache - despite flushing the cache on mobile and enabling cookies, it still doesn't seem to work.  Below is the script I am using - can anyone help!?

```
<?php
define('BASEPATH', true);
require('system/config.php');

if($_GET['e'] != '' && is_numeric($_GET['e'])){$ref_id = $db->EscapeString($_GET['e']); $_SESSION['NGRefCookie'] = $ref_id;}elseif(isset($_SESSION['NGRefCookie'])){$ref_id = $_SESSION['NGRefCookie'];}else{$ref_id = 0;}      

if($config['affiliate_module']){
    if(!empty($_GET['aff']) && is_numeric($_GET['aff'])){
        $aff_id = $db->EscapeString($_GET['aff']); 
        $_SESSION['NGACookie'] = $aff_id;
    }elseif(isset($_SESSION['NGACookie'])){
        $aff_id = $_SESSION['NGACookie'];
    }else{
        $aff_id = 0;
    }       
}

$orign = empty($_GET['orign']) ? '/game/?side=startside' : $_GET['orign'];
if (IS_ONLINE)
{
    header("Location: " . $orign);
    exit;
}

$tSource = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
if(!empty($tSource)){
    $main_domain = parse_url($config['base_url']);
    $http_referer = parse_url($tSource);
    if($http_referer['host'] != $main_domain['host']){
        setcookie('refSource', $db->EscapeString($tSource), time()+60*60*24, '/');
    }
}

$sider = array(
    'login' => 'login',
    'signup' => 'signup',
    'recover' => 'recover',
    'contact' => 'contact'
);
$side = $sider[$_GET['side']];

if (isset($_COOKIE['MZ_Language']) && $languages_supported[$_COOKIE['MZ_Language']])
{
    $langBase_lang = $_COOKIE['MZ_Language'];
}

if (isset($_GET['setLang']) && $languages_supported[$_GET['setLang']])
{
    $lang = $languages_supported[$_GET['setLang']];
    $langBase->language = $lang[0];
    setcookie('MZ_Language', $langBase->language);
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: In what way is it **not working** That is rather to broad a description for us to work with

Comment: Sorry - when a user puts in a username or password and clicks the login button, simply the page refreshes and nothing happens.  There are of of course different possible outcomes when pressing the button such as logging in, incorrect password/username...etc, but nothing happens other than the page refreshing

Comment: Is the "Google Chrome on mobile" Android only? iOS only? Both? Have you tried multiple devices?

Comment: Do you get some error in browser console? or some php errors?

Comment: I have only tried on Android - I will have it tested in iOS too.  And no, I haven't had any errors at all which is bizarre